# Join multiple lists of objects in c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have three lists that contain objects with following structure:

```
List1

 - Status
 - ValueA

List2

- Status
- ValueB

List3

- Status
- ValueC
```

I want to joint the lists by status to get a final list that contains object with following structure:

```
- Status
- ValueA
- ValueB
- ValueC
```

Not every list has all the status. So a simple (left) join won't do it. Any ideas how to achieve the desired result? I tried with

```
var result = from first in list1
    join second in list2 on first.Status equals second.Status into tmp1
    from second in tmp1.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join third in list3 on first.Status equals third.Status into tmp2
    from third in tmp2.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new { ... };
```

But result is missing a status. Here is a full MRE:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<A> first = new List<A>() { new A("FOO", 1), new A("BAR", 2) };
        List<B> second = new List<B>() { new B("FOO", 6), new B("BAR", 3) };
        List<C> third = new List<C>() { new C("BAZ", 5) };
        
        var result = from f in first
            join s in second on f.Status equals s.Status into tmp1
            from s in tmp1.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join t in third on f.Status equals t.Status into tmp2
            from t in tmp2.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new 
            {
                Status = f.Status,
                ValueA = f.ValueA,
                ValueB = s.ValueB,
                ValueC = t.ValueC,
            };

    }
}

public record A(string Status, int ValueA);
public record B(string Status, int ValueB);
public record C(string Status, int ValueC);
```

Comment: because you join on Status .... "BAZ" has no way to join itself to anything in  the resulting merger of `first` + `second` ? you would need something like a right outer join  but you are doing left inner joins?

Comment: @PatrickArtner: No. If you have a status in list A multiple times and you group by status, what should be written into the anonymous object into ValueA, because you have two possibilities for that property now.

Comment: @Oliver a list can contain a status multiple times, but in that case the type of values will be different. Just as shown in my list example.

Comment: @PatrickArtner There is no such thing as a left inner join. Only outer joins can be left/right/full. There's only one type of inner join.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately it is unclear, what should happen, if a status occurs multiple times within one list, cause your aggregate can only hold one value per status.

[One possibility](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mpwMqT) to solve this issue would be:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<A> first = new List<A>() { new A("FOO", 1), new A("BAR", 2) };
        List<B> second = new List<B>() { new B("FOO", 6), new B("BAR", 3) };
        List<C> third = new List<C>() { new C("BAZ", 5) };

        var allStates = first.Select(a => a.Status)
            .Concat(second.Select(b => b.Status))
            .Concat(third.Select(c => c.Status))
            .Distinct();
        
        var result = allStates
            .Select(Status => new 
                    {
                        Status,
                        ValueA = first.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Status == Status),
                        ValueB = second.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Status == Status),
                        ValueC = third.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Status == Status),
                    });
        
        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}

public record A(string Status, int ValueA);
public record B(string Status, int ValueB);
public record C(string Status, int ValueC);
```

Depending on the amount of items that have to be aggregated and the premise that each status occurs only once or never it could make sense to convert your lists to a `Dictionary<string, A>`, `Dictionary<string, B>`, etc. to improve the lookup and do something like this in the aggregate:

```
ValueA = dictFirst.ContainsKey(Status) ? dictFirst[Status] : null
```

For further improvements (this line makes the lookup twice) you could also factor out a method like this

```
private static T GetValueOrDefault<T>(IReadOnlyDictionary<string, T> dict, string status)
{
    dict.TryGetValue(status, out T value);
    return value;
}
```

And within the `.Select()` method call it with

```
ValueA = GetValueOrDefault(firstDict, Status);
```

Creating the dictionary for the list could be done with:

```
var firstDict = first.ToDictionary(a => a.Status);
```

Answer (score 2):

With assumption that status names are unique per list here is a solution
in a single query with help of `switch expressions` (available since C# 8.0):

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

List<A> first = new List<A>() { new A("FOO", 1), new A("BAR", 2) };
List<B> second = new List<B>() { new B("FOO", 6), new B("BAR", 3) };
List<C> third = new List<C>() { new C("BAZ", 5) };

var result = first
    // concat lists together
    .Cast<object>()
    .Concat(second)
    .Concat(third)
    // group on Status value with help of switch expression
    .GroupBy(el => el switch {
        A a => a.Status,
        B b => b.Status,
        C c => c.Status,
    },
    // project groups with anonymous type
    (Status, group) => new { 
        Status,
        ValueA = group.OfType<A>().Select(a => a.ValueA).Cast<int?>().FirstOrDefault(),
        ValueB = group.OfType<B>().Select(b => b.ValueB).Cast<int?>().FirstOrDefault(),
        ValueC = group.OfType<C>().Select(c => c.ValueC).Cast<int?>().FirstOrDefault()
    }); 

public record A(string Status, int ValueA);
public record B(string Status, int ValueB);
public record C(string Status, int ValueC);
```

Comment: I'd really like your approach by using the switch statement within the `.GroupBy`, but I took the liberty to slightly improve the usage of the LINQ operators. Hoping this is okay to you.

Comment: @Oliver, thanks a lot! I learned something new :)

Answer (score 0):

This can't using left join.First you must get all keies,then using all keies left join other lists:

```
var keys = first.Select(item => item.Status).ToList();
keys.AddRange(second.Select(item => item.Status));
keys.AddRange(third.Select(item => item.Status));

keys = keys.Distinct().ToList();

var result = (from k in keys JOIN
       f in first on k equals f.Status into tmp0
       from f in tmp0.DefaultIfEmpty()
       join s in second on k equals s.Status into tmp1
       from s in tmp1.DefaultIfEmpty()
       join t in third on k equals t.Status into tmp2
       from t in tmp2.DefaultIfEmpty()
       select new {
             Status = k,
             ValueA = f?.ValueA,
             ValueB = s?.ValueB,
             ValueC = t?.ValueC,
       }
).ToList();
```